# regEx for my inputTextarea in primefaces jsf

Tags: json, regex, jsf, primefaces, frontend

I need a regEx for my  inputTextarea in primefaces jsf which allows everything except  special characters like `>`,`<` and ' ' '.

```
<h:inputTextarea  maxlength="30" value="#{creditI.cmremarks}" widgetvar = "inputTextcredit">
 <p:keyFilter preventPaste="false" regEx="/[a-z0-9_]/i" />
</h:inputTextarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

would this regex work ? `/[^<>']*/`

Comment: "The value of attribute "regEx" associated with an element type "null" must not contain the '<' character."  I am getting this error

Comment: replace < with &lt; but I suggest you use also a validator to do the same check.

Comment: @WoAiNii can you please explain what kind of validator ?

Comment: @WoAiNii I tried replacing < but still no effect. This regex didn't work.

Comment: Do you get an error or it didn't filter? If the second one remove also the *, for the validator consult [showcase](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/csv/basic.xhtml)

Answer (score 0):

```
<p:inputTextarea value="#{creditI.cmremarks}" maxlength="50" >
    <f:validateRegex pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9.]*$"/>
</p:inputTextarea>
```

It will give error message when use with button

> Regex Pattern not matchedRegex pattern of '^[a-zA-Z0-9.]*$' not matched